# How to get schema name related to user using jdbcDataContext for MS Sql Server 2008 R2?

Tags: java, database, apache, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `MS SQL server 2008 R2` database using `Apache meta-model`Java technology.
I have created a user "USER1" and created login for USER1. Then I created new schema "**user1_schema**" for USER1 and made USER1 owner of this schema. Now I need to get the schema name using jdbcDataContext.
My code to get the schema name is:

```
DataContext jdbcDataContext = DataContextFactory.createJdbcDataContext(Connection);
schema = jdbcDataContext.getSchemaByName("user1_schema"); //return null if no table exist in db
```

These statements work correctly when there are tables in the database but **it returns null value for schema if there are no tables in the database**.

Is there a way to get the name of schema of database in MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 if there are zero tables in the database?